# modify group by query to minimise response time

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table with about 45,000,000 rows
this table has msisdn field ,sub_type field and run date

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*), MSISDN, SUB_TYPE 
FROM <table>
GROUP BY SUB_TYPE, MSISDN 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY MSISDN ASC;
```

It is taking too much time to load.

Is there any better way of writing it?

Kindly give your suggestions.

Thanks,
Anju

Comment: That's about as simple as you can make it. The bottleneck is probably a lack of indexing on `SUB_TYPE` or `MSISDN` or both.

Comment: please post the EXPLAIN...

Comment: You need an index on `(msisdn, sub_type)`